# Can I change the alignment of one element in a VBox?

Tags: javafx, layout, alignment, javafx-8, vbox

If I put controls (or layouts with controls) in a VBox all elements get aligned the same way.  I want to change the alignment of one of those elements like this

[image: VBox Alignment Demo]

I tried to change the alignment of `Button 2`by calling `setAlignment()` on it, but calling `setAlignment()` on an individual element doesn't change the alignment within the VBox.  (The JavaDoc's explanation of Button.setAlignment() is useless.)

I was able to change the alignment of `Button 4` by using an HBox and setting its alignment.  I'd rather not introduce extra Nodes if I don't have to.  Is there a way to change the alignment of one Node in a layout container without having to use another layout?

Here's the code:

```
    public class VBoxAlignmentDemoApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/VBoxAlignmentDemo.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("VBoxAlignmentDemo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

public class VBoxAlignmentDemoController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    VBox vbox;

    @FXML
    Button button2;

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        button2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    }
}

<VBox fx:id="vbox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="vbox.alignment.demo.VBoxAlignmentDemoController">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 1" />
      <Button fx:id="button2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 2" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 3" />
      <HBox alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 4" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: To clarify, `setAlignment()` specifies the alignment of an element's *children*. Setting your `Button` to align right would align any children to the right. Similarly, setting the alignment on your parent VBox would affect all of your buttons which you don't want either.

Comment: Wrapping the button in an HBox, as you've done, is the simplest solution. Why exactly are you opposed to having extra nodes?

Comment: @Michael - To keep things as simple as possible, and to avoid bloating the scene graph.  My scene graph is going to be large as it is.

Comment: Using an `HBox` is keeping it as simple as possible. You are searching for a solution to something you assume will be a problem with no evidence. It's needless. Use an `HBox`, finish the rest of your GUI, and if you can find that using an `HBox` to center that button had a **measurable** performance impact, go back and fix it. Otherwise, don't sweat the small stuff.

Comment: You can use a `GridPane` with a single column, instead of a `VBox`, which will allow you to [set the horizontal alignment of individual child nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHalignment-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.HPos-), and will keep the total number of nodes to a minimum.